# Disable extra mouse buttons Win 7 and wireless mouse HK-250

Tags: windows-7, mouse-buttons

The extra buttons on the side of my wireless mouse are a nuisance.
My large hands always touches one of them when least needed.
I am looking for a way to disable the extra buttons in Win 7

Answer (score 1):

Most likely that kind of mouses comes with a driver an application try install or download it if you don't have, that should help you.